# Is there an equivalent for Glob in D Phobos?

Tags: d, glob, phobos

In python I can use glob to search path patterns. This for instance:

```python
import glob
for entry in glob.glob("/usr/*/python*"):
    print(entry)
```

Would print this:

```
/usr/share/python3
/usr/share/python3-plainbox
/usr/share/python
/usr/share/python-apt
/usr/include/python3.5m
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3m
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python3.5
/usr/bin/python3.5m
/usr/bin/python2
/usr/lib/python3
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python3.5
```

How would I `glob` or make a glob equivalent in in D?

**------Updated on Sep 12 2017------**

I wrote a small D module to do Glob in D: https://github.com/workhorsy/d-glob

Comment: [It seems](http://forum.dlang.org/post/mailman.378.1384214006.9546.digitalmars-d@puremagic.com) that with D's standard library you can only do path filtering (e.g. `dirEntries`). Worth an enhancement request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the answers above worked 100% the same as Glob on Windows and Linux. So I made a small D module that does Glob the right way. Hopefully people find it useful:

https://github.com/workhorsy/d-glob

```dlang
import std.stdio : stdout;
import glob : glob;

foreach (entry ; glob("/usr/*/python*")) {
    stdout.writefln("%s", entry);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only work on a Posix system, you can directly call `glob.h`. Here's a simple example that shows how easy it is to interface with the Posix API:

```d
void main()
{
    import std.stdio;
    import glob : glob; 
    foreach(entry; glob("/usr/*/python*"))
        writeln(entry);
}
```

You can compile this e.g. with `rdmd main.d` (rdmd does simple dependency management) or `dmd main.d glob.d` and it yields a similar output as yours on my machine.

`glob.d` was generated by [dstep](https://github.com/jacob-carlborg/dstep) and is enhanced with a convenience D-style wrapper (first function). Please note that this isn't perfect and a better way would be to expose a range  API instead of allocating the entire array.

```d
/* Copyright (C) 1991-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This file is part of the GNU C Library.

   The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
   modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
   version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

   The GNU C Library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
   Lesser General Public License for more details.

   You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License along with the GNU C Library; if not, see
   <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */

string[] glob(string pattern)
{
    import std.string;
    string[] results;
    glob_t glob_result;
    glob(pattern.toStringz, 0, null, &glob_result);
    for (uint i = 0; i < glob_result.gl_pathc; i++)
    {
        results ~= glob_result.gl_pathv[i].fromStringz().idup;
    }

    globfree(&glob_result);
    return results;
}

import core.stdc.config;

extern (C):

enum _GLOB_H = 1;

/* We need `size_t' for the following definitions.  */
alias c_ulong __size_t;
alias c_ulong size_t;

/* The GNU CC stddef.h version defines __size_t as empty.  We need a real
   definition.  */

/* Bits set in the FLAGS argument to `glob'.  */
enum GLOB_ERR = 1 << 0; /* Return on read errors.  */
enum GLOB_MARK = 1 << 1; /* Append a slash to each name.  */
enum GLOB_NOSORT = 1 << 2; /* Don't sort the names.  */
enum GLOB_DOOFFS = 1 << 3; /* Insert PGLOB->gl_offs NULLs.  */
enum GLOB_NOCHECK = 1 << 4; /* If nothing matches, return the pattern.  */
enum GLOB_APPEND = 1 << 5; /* Append to results of a previous call.  */
enum GLOB_NOESCAPE = 1 << 6; /* Backslashes don't quote metacharacters.  */
enum GLOB_PERIOD = 1 << 7; /* Leading `.' can be matched by metachars.  */
enum GLOB_MAGCHAR = 1 << 8; /* Set in gl_flags if any metachars seen.  */
enum GLOB_ALTDIRFUNC = 1 << 9; /* Use gl_opendir et al functions.  */
enum GLOB_BRACE = 1 << 10; /* Expand "{a,b}" to "a" "b".  */
enum GLOB_NOMAGIC = 1 << 11; /* If no magic chars, return the pattern.  */
enum GLOB_TILDE = 1 << 12; /* Expand ~user and ~ to home directories. */
enum GLOB_ONLYDIR = 1 << 13; /* Match only directories.  */
enum GLOB_TILDE_CHECK = 1 << 14; /* Like GLOB_TILDE but return an error
                      if the user name is not available.  */
enum __GLOB_FLAGS = GLOB_ERR | GLOB_MARK | GLOB_NOSORT | GLOB_DOOFFS | GLOB_NOESCAPE | GLOB_NOCHECK | GLOB_APPEND | GLOB_PERIOD | GLOB_ALTDIRFUNC | GLOB_BRACE | GLOB_NOMAGIC | GLOB_TILDE | GLOB_ONLYDIR | GLOB_TILDE_CHECK;

/* Error returns from `glob'.  */
enum GLOB_NOSPACE = 1; /* Ran out of memory.  */
enum GLOB_ABORTED = 2; /* Read error.  */
enum GLOB_NOMATCH = 3; /* No matches found.  */
enum GLOB_NOSYS = 4; /* Not implemented.  */

/* Previous versions of this file defined GLOB_ABEND instead of
   GLOB_ABORTED.  Provide a compatibility definition here.  */

/* Structure describing a globbing run.  */

struct glob_t
{
    __size_t gl_pathc; /* Count of paths matched by the pattern.  */
    char** gl_pathv; /* List of matched pathnames.  */
    __size_t gl_offs; /* Slots to reserve in `gl_pathv'.  */
    int gl_flags; /* Set to FLAGS, maybe | GLOB_MAGCHAR.  */

    /* If the GLOB_ALTDIRFUNC flag is set, the following functions
       are used instead of the normal file access functions.  */
    void function (void*) gl_closedir;

    void* function (void*) gl_readdir;

    void* function (const(char)*) gl_opendir;

    int function (const(char)*, void*) gl_lstat;
    int function (const(char)*, void*) gl_stat;
}

/* If the GLOB_ALTDIRFUNC flag is set, the following functions
   are used instead of the normal file access functions.  */

/* Do glob searching for PATTERN, placing results in PGLOB.
   The bits defined above may be set in FLAGS.
   If a directory cannot be opened or read and ERRFUNC is not nil,
   it is called with the pathname that caused the error, and the
   `errno' value from the failing call; if it returns non-zero
   `glob' returns GLOB_ABEND; if it returns zero, the error is ignored.
   If memory cannot be allocated for PGLOB, GLOB_NOSPACE is returned.
   Otherwise, `glob' returns zero.  */

int glob (
    const(char)* __pattern,
    int __flags,
    int function (const(char)*, int) __errfunc,
    glob_t* __pglob);

/* Free storage allocated in PGLOB by a previous `glob' call.  */
void globfree (glob_t* __pglob);
```

Comment: Even though this isn't using Phobos, it looks like a good enough solution. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to [file an enhancement request](https://issues.dlang.org/enter_bug.cgi) for Phobos ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for [`std.file.dirEntries()`](https://dlang.org/library/std/file/dir_entries.html).

Here's example from the documentation:

```d
// Iterate over all D source files in current directory and all its
// subdirectories
auto dFiles = dirEntries("","*.{d,di}",SpanMode.depth);
foreach(d; dFiles)
    writeln(d.name);
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work. The glob patterns don't seem to work across directories.

Comment: `dirEntries` is a range, so you can just filter through it, but it will of course iterate through all files :/

Answer (score 0):

Basically you don't need to do all this complicated stuff with headers, C and so on, and so forth. This should do the thing:

```
auto dirIter = dirEntries("/usr", "*/python*", SpanMode.shallow);
foreach(dirFile; dirIter) {
    // Process the result as needed
```

Comment: [`SpanMode.shallow`](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_file.html#.SpanMode) will only iterate over one level - hence your example doesn't return any file. See e.g. [this DPaste](https://dpaste.dzfl.pl/bde2c6825106). Unfortunately there is no simple way to do this with D yet :/

Comment: I guess OP wanted to list all of the directories starting with `python` and located in `/usr/*`, no?)

Comment: Yes, but dirEntries with `usr` and `shallow` will only look one level deep (e. g.  `/usr/share`)